# Ubuntu 14.01 gives internal errors, system update crashes

Tags: crash

Ubuntu keeps on giving me internal errors, when I boot the system up it gives several internal errors, and when I try to update or install a program, the updater and the software center shut down.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/la7M4.jpg
These are the outputs I get when I give the command sudo apt-get update.

Could anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: What exactly did you change with the language settings?

Comment: I changed it from Dutch to English, in my account and in the system settings

Comment: It makes no sense that switching language would cause package problems; it's probably a coincidence. Can you edit the question and show us the complete output of `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: I changed the question, and put the output in the link

Comment: Ubuntu 14.01 are you sure?  Do you mean 14.04.1?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have different problems in your output. First of all, remove the offending Spotify repository files (don't worry, they will be created again later):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_*
```

Then fix the GPG key error ([source](https://superuser.com/a/505194/278831)):

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 082CCEDF94558F59
```

Finally, issue an update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

---

Regarding the internal errors, I would try to clear the list of old program crashes:

```
sudo rm /var/crash/*
```

Comment: Great. If my answer satisfies you, please consider accepting it. Thanks. :)